# java / mysql / slow

Tags: java, mysql

Point here being:

1.SET query_cache_type = 0; RESET QUERY CACHE ;

2.run any query within heidisql(or any other client side UI) --> execution, say **45** milisec

3.run same query with below code --> execution say **120** milisec. And the diff rises exponentialy with other queries

4.the things added/removed that did not helped at all commented out

```
      long sql_execution_time = 0;
      String url = "jdbc:mysql://my.net:3306/test";

      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

      Properties props = new Properties();
      props.setProperty("user", "root");
      props.setProperty("password", "pwd");

      //kao not recomended
      //http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html
      //props.setProperty("autoReconnect", "true");

      props.setProperty("characterEncoding", "UTF-8");
      //props.setProperty("useReadAheadInput", "true");
      //props.setProperty("SelectMethod", "direct");
      //props.setProperty("responseBuffering", "adaptive");



      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,props);
      String sql = "select g.*,t.id_tezaver_obfuscated,group_concat(t.data_source) as taxonomy_src,substring_index(group_concat(t.term order by t.eunis ),',',1) as term,(select count(t2.term) from tezaver t2 where t2.id_tezaver = g.id_tezaver and t2.l2 <> 'la') as c from galery_1 g left join tezaver t on g.id_tezaver = t.id_tezaver and t.l2 = 'la'  where 1 = 1 group by  g.id_galery  order by g.id_galery asc limit 0,18;";

      //java.sql.Statement stm = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
      java.sql.Statement stm = con.createStatement();



      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis(); 

      ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);


      Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
      long endTime = cal1.getTimeInMillis();
      sql_execution_time = endTime - startTime;
      long krneki = sql_execution_time;
      startTime = endTime;
      stm.close();
      con.close();
      result = String.valueOf(sql_execution_time);
```

Comment: Just as a sidenote: you can use `System.currentTimeMillis()` for timings instead of always creating a new `Calendar` instance.

Comment: close the resultset, statement and connection and set all three to null, all this in a finally block. you may have a memory leak ;-) btw is the query slow on the first time as well (after JVM restart) ?

Comment: Could you post another query wich is significantly slower?

Answer (score 1):

Its important to understand that your java code is not just executing the query. Its doing a few other things too;

- loading the mysql driver
- opening a connection
- creating a few objects

You are timing the whole thing, not just the execution of the query. The UI is probably behaving differently. It may just be timing how long the query takes to execute.

Its not really logical to compare the two in terms of performance.

Comment: > 1. System.currentTimeMillis() does not change a thing2. forget this part a I dont get how can ENRTER be equal submit , writing amswer ....

Answer (score 0):

> 1.System.currentTimeMillis() does not change a thing
>   2.Jes same thing right after jvm restart
>   3.example:

two sqls, heidisql 0.093 sec, java 0,9 sec (calling stored proc, so there are no 2 calls)

[see timing here on bottom of page](http://agrozoo.net/jsp/Galery.jsp?p100=18)

Select g.*,t.id_tezaver_obfuscated,group_concat(t.data_source) as taxonomy_src,SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_concat(t.term order by t.eunis ),',',1) as term,(select count(t2.term) from tezaver t2 where t2.id_tezaver = g.id_tezaver and t2.l2 <> 'la') as c from galery_1 g left join tezaver t on g.id_tezaver = t.id_tezaver and t.l2 = 'la'  where 1 = 1 group by  g.id_galery  order by g.id_galery desc LIMIT 0,18;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();

3.loading the mysql driver - OK in example, in real world with conection pulling that does not count, cnonection opening - it is already opened, a few objects - mybe.